# operate over values of a dictionary when values are lists

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
data = {'ACCOUNT_CLOSURE': ['account closure',
  'close account',
  'close bank',
  'terminate account',
  'account deletion',
  'cancel account',
  'account cancellation'],
 'ACCOUNT_CHANGE': ['change my account',
  'switch my account',
  'change from private into savings',
  'convert into family package',
  'change title of the account',
  'make title account to family',
  'help me access the documentation']}
```

I want to go through each key and subsequently the elements of the values and drop the stopwords, so I do:

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

for key, values in data.items():
    data[key] = [value for value in values if value not in stop_words]
```

but this returns the exact same dictionary as my original one. I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```py
>     data[key] = [value for value in values if value not in stop_words]
> ```

You're comparing the full string (`value`) against the words in `stop_words`, when you actually want to *remove words **from*** the string - for which you need to `split` each string into words and check each word to filter before joining them up again:

```py
def remove_stopwords(orig, swList):
    return ' '.join(w for w in str(orig).split() if w.lower() not in swList)
```

You can apply this function to every string.

```py
stop_words = set(sw.lower() for sw in stopwords.words("english"))


for key, values in data.items():
    # data[key] = [remove_stopwords(v, stop_words) for v in values] # keeps empty strings
    swFil_gen = (remove_stopwords(v,stop_words) for v in values) # generator [not list]
    data[key] = [cleanStr for cleanStr in swFil_gen if cleanStr] # no empty strings
```

<sup>[The `.lower()`s make everything lower case so that the comparisons are case-insensitive, although it's not really necessary in this case- but then, neither is `set` since `stopwords.words("english")` does not contain any duplicate values.]</sup>

---

You can also use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) like

```py
# data = {... # OR [if you don't want to change data]
cleaned_data = {key: [cleanStr for cleanStr in (
    remove_stopwords(v, stop_words) for v in values
) if cleanStr] for key, values in data.items()}
```

---

`cleaned_data` [or `data` after the `for` loop] should look like

> ```py
> {'ACCOUNT_CLOSURE': ['account closure',
>   'close account',
>   'close bank',
>   'terminate account',
>   'account deletion',
>   'cancel account',
>   'account cancellation'],
>  'ACCOUNT_CHANGE': ['change account',
>   'switch account',
>   'change private savings',
>   'convert family package',
>   'change title account',
>   'make title account family',
>   'help access documentation']}
> ```